# Angular: Module or Component corresponds to a page?

Tags: angular

Should we have a module per page or Component per page?

Is it a good design pattern to have one module for the entire site and load different components for page transitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Assuming that by `page` you actually mean `screen`. Mentioning that because in SPA everything is, technically, single page.]

Its somewhere in between.

Module encapsulates similar features together. Those features usually spans more than one page and then page definitely spans many components.

In general, you want to have components as small as possible which in turn mean as narrow task per component as possible and then you build component tree by composing simple components.

When it comes to modules, you bundle together features that make sense together into a module.

Lets say you have an invoicing application where you can do:

- users management
- inventory management
- clients management
- invoices management
  ...

Each one of those is a candidate for a feature module and then each would contain many pages which would be build from many components.

Hope that helps.